# Xamarin Label Binding Context

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There seems to be a problem with my binding context

I've change the bindingcontext to this, I've tried hardcoding the value, that did not work either. I've checked the value of Issue.Createdby, and it gets filled with an username but it is not displayed. This is the only binding I got a problem with.

Constructor of the page

```
public EditIssuePage(UIIssueVM issue, IssueCarouselPage parentPage)
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    _parentPage = parentPage;
                    Issue = issue;
                    StatusValues = Issue.PossibleStatusValues;
                    SeverityValues = Issue.PossibleSeverityValues;
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<UIImageVM>();
                    BindingContext = issue;

                }
```

Onappearing of the page, where the Issue.CreatedBy is filled but not displayed on screen.  I can add the GetcurrentUserName method if you want, but it seems irrelevant due to it getting filled correctly.

```
        protected async override void OnAppearing()

                    if (Issue.IsNew)
                    {
                        Title = "New Event";
                        severity3.Opacity = 1;
                        Issue.Severity = IssueSeverity.Medium;
                        Issue.Status = IssueStatus.Done;
                        Issue.CreatedBy = App.Client.GetCurrentUsername();
                    }
```

XAML part of the code

```
     <!--Date Created-->
                    <Frame OutlineColor="#FBB040">
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="6" BackgroundColor="Black">
                            <Label Text="TIME AND DATE: " Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Created, Converter={StaticResource DateToTextConverter}}"  Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>

                    <!--REPORTED BY-->
                    <Frame OutlineColor="#FBB040">
                        <StackLayout  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="6" BackgroundColor="Black">
                            <Label Text="REPORTED BY: " Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}"/>
                            <Label x:Name="createdBy" Text="{Binding CreatedBy}"  Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
```

How the Issue code looks like that it binds to

```
  public class UIIssueVM : ViewModels.Issue.IssueVM, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
        public UIIssueVM()
        {
                Id = 0;
                Title = "";
                Description = "";
                Created = DateTime.Now;
                Edited = DateTime.Now;
            }

        public UIIssueVM(bool bIsNew)
        {
            IsNew = true;

            Id = 0;
            Title = "";
            Description = "";
            CreatedBy = App.Client.GetCurrentUsername();
            Created = DateTime.Now;
            Edited = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public UIIssueVM(ViewModels.Issue.IssueVM issue)
        {
            LocationId = issue.LocationId;
            Id = issue.Id;
            Title = issue.Title;
            Description = issue.Description;
            Longitude = issue.Longitude;
            Latitude = issue.Latitude;
            Status = issue.Status;
            Severity = issue.Severity;
            Created = issue.Created;
            Edited = issue.Edited;
            CreatedBy = issue.CreatedBy;
        }
        public ViewModels.Issue.NewIssueVM CreateNewIssueVM()
        {
            ViewModels.Issue.NewIssueVM issue = new ViewModels.Issue.NewIssueVM();
            issue.LocationId = LocationId;
            issue.Title = Title;
            issue.Description = Description;
            issue.Longitude = Longitude;
            issue.Latitude = Latitude;
            issue.Status = Status;
            issue.Severity = Severity;
            return issue;
        }


      public ViewModels.Issue.IssueVM CreateUpdatedIssueVM()
            {
                ViewModels.Issue.IssueVM issue = new ViewModels.Issue.IssueVM();
                issue.Id = Id;
                issue.LocationId = LocationId;
                issue.Title = Title;
                issue.Description = Description;
                issue.Longitude = Longitude;
                issue.Latitude = Latitude;
                issue.Status = Status;
                issue.Severity = Severity;
                issue.CreatedBy = issue.CreatedBy;
                return issue;
            }



    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Update!"); //ok
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                //PropertyChanged is always null and shouldn't.
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

 public bool Changed
        {
            get
            {
                return this.IssueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                IssueChanged = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string TitleEx
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Title;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.Title != value)
                {
                    this.Title = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    Changed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public string DescriptionEx
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Description;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.Description != value)
                {
                    this.Description = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    Changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: does UIIssueVM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Changing the edit, it does implement it.

Comment: it doesn't for CreatedBy, which is the specific property you're having a problem with?

Comment: I'm having problem with CreatedBy actually, so I see. Do I just make another like the descrptionex and TitleEx?

Comment: well, yes.  You can't bind to a property that doesn't exist.